# What major difficulties have you encountered in approaching training and solution development with Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I have personally completed a development with Hyperledger Fabric for a project that will go live in a few months.

I must say that the main difficulties encountered were:

- Very varied technological stack: scripting, dockerization,
  cryptography, ...
- Conceptually complex technology
- Very few resources beyond the official documentation

I would very much like to know what difficulties you have encountered. Which is your top 3 list?
I personally missed hyperledger-composer.

Answer (score 3):

I totally agree with you on the first point, I felt particularly as a chain-code developer frustrated about the variety of technical skills that are supposed to be mastered in order to bootstrap a network to test things like private data collection or programmatic access-control.

I also felt overwhelmed when I was recruited into a company where I was supposed to perform development and operations by myself when these two technical roles are widely different and large to be performed by the same person.
But I don't agree with you for the second point. Distributed systems in general are complex because of the very nature of the problem they are addressing ( Double Spending ) not to mention Distributed Ledger Technology which takes it a step further. Understanding the complex software architecture may help you develop a more sophisticated and strong opinion, particularly when you address fields like software architecture later.

I partially agree with you for the third point because it is a sad truth about any fancy technology related to Open Source Project. (Documentation is good in itself, but lacks a lot of structuring and remain sometimes unclear)

So for me, the first three difficulties would

- Technical skills related to DevOps and Security
- Unclear Documentations
- Confusion of Recruiter about the different technical roles needed to build and maintain a HyperLedger Fabric Project

Comment: Nice sharing, thanks! On my second point, of course, it is necessary to understand the architecture. You can't avoid it. 
Despite this it has taken me some effort and I am convinced there may be a way to make understanding easier.

Answer (score 0):

I faced difficulties due to:

1. They mentioned some architectural procedures on their documents, but they did not implemented those security related issues on version 1.x where they implemented most of those on version 2.x. They just hide their lacking on version 1.x but at least they may mentioned those as their future implementation. They may do this for marketing purpose but I faced tough situations to handle those.
2. Lack of proper official documentations, very few resources beyond the official documentation
3. My knowledge gap on DevOps and public key cryptography

Comment: Thanks! I know hyperledger-composer is deprecated, that's the why I missed it :-)